# sending of json data between client and php server

Tags: php, json

this is the server side code

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 2016 00:00:00 GMT');

header('Content-type: application/json');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$data = array("Hello", $id);
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

and this is the client side code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    function show(json) {
        alert(json);
    }
    function run() {
        $.getJSON("/localhost/jserver1.php",
            { id: 567 },
        show);
    }
    window.onload=run;
</script>
</head>
<body>
    JSON Test Page.
</body>
</html>
```

What i want to do here is i want to send messages between client and server using php and json. when i run the server side code i am getting the output as hello with the id given in the url in the localhost,but when i run the client side code i am getting only the body of the html page,I am not getting the alert with the input id that is there in the run method.Please someone tell me what is the problem

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
    $.getJSON("URL",  
            { id: 567 },
           show 
            );
window.onload=run;
```

Use -

```
    $.getJSON("URL",  
            { id: 567 },
           function(response){
             show(response);
      });

window.onload=run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Still very bad code, you should split up your files. But here we go:

```
<?php
if($_GET['id']) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $data = array("Hello", $id);
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {

?>
<html>
<head>  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show(json) {
       alert(json);
    }
    function run() {
       $.ajax({
            url : '/whatever/this/page/is',
            type : 'GET',
            data : 'id=567',
            success: function(res) {
                show(res);
            }
       });
    }


            window.onload=run;

        </script>

</head>

<body>

    JSON Test Page.

</body>
</html>
<? 
}
```

Comment: Files seem to be split up, the formatting just bad. I changed formatting but it is not yet approved.

Comment: still the same i am getting after trying the above code.please someone help me in a proper way

Comment: @Vishwa, then you're not linking to the page in the `URL` correctly.

Comment: i have given the link to the server page in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the **/** in front of **/localhost/jserver1.php** and adding **http://**.

Currently it refers to **localhost/localhost/jserver1.php**

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code

```
function show(json) {
       alert(JSON.stringify(json));
}
```